# When to use what or who

Tags: word-choice, who

Which is correct?

> I'm what you made me

or

> I'm who you made me

Comment: Personally, I don't much like usages like [*He is who he is*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+is+what+he+is%2CHe+is+who+he+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20what%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20who%20he%20is%3B%2Cc0). As that chart shows, it's still much less common than *He is **what** he is*, but it has started to gain some traction in recent decades (having been virtually unknown prior to 1960). I think it's just the influence of non-native speakers, not an enduring change in language use.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends.**

If you are talking about the whole person in this context, then "**who**".

If the sentiment is, for example, "You're a monster!", then I would go with "I am **what** you made me."